Drools error in a springboot pod: "message":"Unable to build index of kmodule.xml
"class":"org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject","message":"Unable to build index of kmodule.xml url=jar:nested:/app/microservice.jar/!BOOT-INF/lib/apa-acl-rules-kjar-1.0.0.jar!/META-INF/kmodule.xml\nbegin 42, end 41, length 41"}
Hi,
I am trying to read a KJAR project from classpath of springboot project, I am using drools 8.44.0.Final version:
I have the dependency in my springboot project:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rsv.architecture-acl</groupId>
        <artifactId>apa-acl-rules-kjar</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

My kjar project is ok in its structure, all works fine in my local machine, but when I deploy it in a container I am getting next error:
"class":"org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject","message":"Unable to build index of kmodule.xml url=jar:nested:/app/microservice.jar/!BOOT-INF/lib/apa-acl-rules-kjar-1.0.0.jar!/META-INF/kmodule.xml\nbegin 42, end 41, length 41"}
Please, somebody could help me to resolve the error?
Thanks in advance

If it works locally but not in your container, you need to start looking at what's different between your two runtime environments. Are you using the same architecture for your image and your local working environment? Is the security on your container runtime too restrictive? etc.
